# gauge.js - Relative URL does not work but absolute URL does in Django 1.10

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-templates

I have been experimenting with [gauge.js](https://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/), and reproduced the working 'Usage' code presented on the link only when using  an absolute URL, but **not** when using a relative URL.

I did not find anything similar on the [Github Issue Tracker](https://github.com/bernii/gauge.js/issues?page=2&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen)

### Working Code

```
<canvas id="foo"></canvas>
<script>
    var opts = {
      lines: 12,
      angle: 0.15,
      lineWidth: 0.44,
      pointer: {
         length: 0.9,
         strokeWidth: 0.035,
         color: '#000000'
      },
      limitMax: 'false', 
      percentColors: [[0.0, "#a9d70b" ], [0.50, "#f9c802"], [1.0, "#ff0000"]], // !!!!
      strokeColor: '#E0E0E0',
      generateGradient: true
    };
    var target = document.getElementById('foo');
    var gauge = new Gauge(target).setOptions(opts);
    gauge.maxValue = 3000;
    gauge.animationSpeed = 32;
    gauge.set(2250);
</script>

<script src="https://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/dist/gauge.min.js"></script>
```

### Issue

If I replace the above absolute URL with a relative URL, the gauge disappears. What I did was copy the `gauge.min.js` code from [here](https://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/), and place the file inside my static folder. (Working tree directory below)

```
<script src="../../static/lineoee/gauge.min.js"></script>
```

The above relative URL should be pointing to a valid directory, however I am getting:

> (index):224 Uncaught ReferenceError: Gauge is not defined at `var gauge = new Gauge(target).setOptions(opts);`

### Working Tree Directory

```
    │   ├── static
│   │   └── lineoee
│   │       ├── gauge.min.js
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── linedetails
│   │   │   ├── index.html
│   │   │   └── index.html.save
│   │   └── lineoee
│   │       ├── index.html     <-- I am linking gauge.min.js from here
│   │       ├── index.html.save
```

### Urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from lineoee.views import index
from lineoee.views import details

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'lineoee/$', index, name='index'),
    url(r'linedetails/', details, name='details'),
]
```

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

**Side Note:**

- I have specific performance concerns such as *limited internet* and
  *fast reload times*.
- Application will be deployed only on a *localhost*.

### EDIT

As per the answer below, using `../static/lineoee/gauge.js` I get the following message on my python console:

> "GET /static/lineoee/gauge.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative URLs are *not* relative to the on-disk location of your templates, they are relative to the current URL. So if you access the page using the URL

```
http://localhost/lineoee/
```

the relative URL for the Javascript resource would be

```
../static/lineoee/gauge.min.js
```

This is probably why it is a good idea to use absolute URLs for static resources as URL configurations can always change. I suggest you to use the [`static`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static) template tag which takes care of these details for you:

```
{% load static %}
...
{% static 'lineoee/gauge.min.js' %}
```

Comment: I can confirm that the actual file containing the source code is not empty. For some reason on clearing the cache now I am able to view the source code.